# Robot framework exit status of a command is wrong?

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to execute a command remotely through Robot Framework which is failing through Robot framework and giving me the wrong exit status of 13.

But if we run this manually exit status of `TTman.sh` is 112 which is actually pass(Not the standard return codes).

am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: which command is giving the wrong exit status?

Comment: @BryanOakley `TTman.sh` when executed manually gives `112` as return code but `robotframework` always gives me `13`

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting the remote code of the remote command, in fact the RC 13 you are getting from the run is most probably from the robotframework - on run completion its RC is the number of failed cases. I.e. 13 cases should have failed, when you observed this.

To get the return code of your command, a few changes in the case are needed; this is how the semi-last line should look like, with explanations below:

```
${rc}=    Execute Command    your_command_from_the_question &>/dev/null; echo $?
```

First, all the output of your command (stdout & stderr) is redirected to /dev/null - to not return it. Then the special var `$?` is printed - it holds the RC of the last executed command (and is available in most *sh variants, like bash).

Finally, that value is stored in the `${rc}` robotframework variable, and you can do whatever checks you need on it, further in the case.

This approach has one drawback - as stderr is hidden, you will not be able to see any errors coming from running the command. But if it was not, then they would be interleaved with the RC, which would have required further processing of the `{rc}` var, to get the desired value. If you need it (the stderr output in case of failures), change accordingly.

P.S. don't add screenshots of a source in a question, it is much less usable than a text version.